# c++ is const pointer to literal valid?

Tags: c++, pointers, constants, literals, lvalue

I know lvalues can be converted into const reference. I'm curious if I can get a pointer to those lvalues.

If I write

```
const int* p = &3; //ERROR: lvalue required as unary operand '&'
```

I get this error. However,

```
const int* p = &((const int&)3);
```

this compiles. In this case, is the result of *p guaranteed to be 3?

Comment: long story short - c-style cast almost always means at best implementation-defined behaviour, at worst undefined behaviour.

Comment: But this should compile with static_cast<const int&>(3) too.

Comment: It does, but it's still UB. static_cast can only be used to cast back to the original type.

Comment: @RichardHodges That's nonsense. `static_cast` can perform a variety of casts between pairs of distinct types. `static_cast<const int&>(3)` is, in itself, perfectly fine and legal. The UB arises out of trying to use an object after its lifetime has ended, not out of creating that object in the first place via a cast.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik you're right. It can perform a legal conversion. I was conflating static_cast with reinterpret_cast.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This constructs a temporary `int(3)` and binds it to a const reference. `p` is made to point to that temporary. The lifetime of the temporary is extended to match that of the reference - but the reference itself is a temporary and is destroyed at the semicolon, leaving `p` a dangling pointer. Any attempt to use `p` afterwards (other than assigning a new value to it) would exhibit undefined behavior.

Comment: agree - demo here: https://godbolt.org/g/5nKT49 - `fooint` gets called with zero argument, not 3.

Comment: But this is legal, right? `const int& p = (const int&)3;
const int* q = &p;`  Might be worth mentioning.

Comment: @AndyG Yes, I believe this is legal. It's just run of the mill temporary lifetime extension. One doesn't need a cast, could just write `const int& p = 3;`